# Create name and email from query mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have table which stores data under field number and value fields.I am trying to get the records in array or object formate but unable to do this.

My query look like this :

```
    $signups = "SELECT *
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rg_lead_detail
                WHERE 
                (form_id = '7' AND CAST(field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(1.3 AS DECIMAL)) OR
                (form_id = '7' AND CAST(field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(1.6 AS DECIMAL)) OR
                (form_id = '7' AND field_number = '5')

                ";

    $getappt = $wpdb->get_results($signups);
    foreach ($getappt as $value) { 

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($value);echo "</pre>";
    echo '<pre>'.$value->value;
    $email = $value->value;
}
```

its printing results like this 
OUTPUT :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 10355
    [lead_id] => 423
    [form_id] => 7
    [field_number] => 1.3
    [value] => Bruce
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 10356
    [lead_id] => 423
    [form_id] => 7
    [field_number] => 1.6
    [value] => Faber
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 10357
    [lead_id] => 423
    [form_id] => 7
    [field_number] => 2.1
    [value] => 40 Harmony Lane
)
```

There are two issues in this query first it fetch all records against `form_id =7` not with the field field_number `(2)` how can i set the first 3 objects array into one single array so i can fetch the user name with email.first object array have first name value and second object array have last name values and third one email.
Resolved the first issue using this query.

```
"SELECT *
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rg_lead_detail
                WHERE 
                (form_id = '7' AND FORMAT(field_number,2) = FORMAT(1.3,2)) OR
                (form_id = '7' AND FORMAT(field_number,2) = FORMAT(1.6,2)) OR
                (form_id = '7' AND field_number = '5')

            "
```

Comment: what does the second picture bring to this? please to write a better question

Comment: Why dont you use the value of `lead` as a key to combine user data? You can strip it off later using array_values().

Comment: @syck if i use group by with lead id then it returns only return first value array.

Comment: I will try to explain in an answer. But I do not understand why you removed the table example and put in the query a second time, as well as I do not understand the unsigned first comment. I have never seen a _second_ picture in that question.

Comment: @syck i was trying to add pictures of db structure and values but unable that's why i removed that.I fetched the values only issue is left of combining values into one array like (fname,lname,email) but at the moment i am getting all the three in 3 objects like in question.

Comment: It worked for me... i saw at least one pic, otherwise I would not have proposed grouping by lead_id... I think they carried important information. Of course you can add that in text form as well. Posting almost the same query twice reduces clarity, maybe remove the things you could already solve by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$getappt = $wpdb->get_results($signups);
$list = array();
foreach ($getappt as $data) { 
    $list[$data->lead_id]['f'.$data->field_number] = $data->value;
}

var_dump($list);
```

will give you a two-keyed array that has the value of lead as the first key, thus combining the data of a single customer into a sub-array. It should contain something like

```
array(
    423 => array(
        'f1.3' => 'Bruce',
        'f1.6' => 'Faber',
        'f2.1' => '40 Harmony Lane',
    )
)
```

Prefixing the f is for PHP not truncating the field number to an integer. I believe this will not happen anyways, but I did not try. After all PHP is a weakly typed language.